# Accessing and Modifying a list from a View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a program to allow the user to create recipes. Among other attributes, the recipes will be associated with a number of steps/instructions. I've written the view as follows:

```
@model Recipe.Models.Input

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style>
.editor-field textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>

<h2>New Recipe</h2>

<div class="col-md-4">
<h3>General Information</h3>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.name)<br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.name)<br />
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.description)<br />
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.description, "Recipe Description")
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.prepCookTime)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.prepCookTime)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.cookTime)<br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.cookTime)
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<h3>Nutritional Information (?)</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddStep", "Input"))
{
    <h3>Steps</h3>
    <!-- functionality for adding an indefinate amount of steps -->

    <div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.step)<br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.step)<br />
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.stepDescription)<br />
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.stepDescription)<br />
        </div>
        <br /><input type="submit" value="Add Step" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- functionality for displaying added steps -->

        <h6>Number of steps: @Model.Steps.Count</h6> <!-- This is not changing -->

    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Recipe.Models;

namespace Recipe.Controllers
{
public class InputController : Controller
{

    public static int stepCount { get; set; }
    private Input input;

    public InputController()
    {
        input = new Input();
        stepCount = 0;
    }
    // GET: Input
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(input);
    }

    public ActionResult AddStep(string step, string stepDescription)
    {
        //called when button is pressed
        input.Steps.Add(step); //add input step to list
        input.StepDescriptions.Add(stepDescription); //add input description to list
        Debug.WriteLine(input.Steps.Count());

        stepCount++;
        Debug.WriteLine(stepCount);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", input);
    }
}
}
```

(I apologize for the weird formatting, it copies over strangely.)
I've found that, given this setup, I have extremely limited access to the list from the view, itself. I can add an element to the list, but it seems that its discarded as soon as the AddStep action method returns. Each time I run it, the view prints out "Number of steps: 1", no matter how many items I add. Am I missing something, or is this an improper way of accessing list?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I suppose the Model might be important...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Recipe.Models
{

public class Input
{
    /* Properties */
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; } //represent the name of the recipe
    //public file? imageField
    [Display(Name = "Store Number")]
    public int store { get; set; } //represent store number
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string description { get; set; } //represent recipe description
    [Display(Name = "Estimated Preparation Time")]
    public DateTime prepCookTime { get; set; } //represent preparation time
    [Display(Name = "Estimated Cook Time")]
    public DateTime cookTime { get; set; } //represent cooking time

    [Display(Name = "Serving Size")]
    public int servingSize { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Number of Servings")]
    public int servingNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Unit of Measurement")]
    public string unitOfMeasurement { get; set; }

    public List<string> Steps { get; set; } //list to hold all steps associated with recipe
    public List<string> StepDescriptions { get; set; } //list to hold all step descriptions
    [Display(Name = "Step title/overview")]
    public string step { get; set; } //string to hold step title
    [Display(Name = "Step Description")]
    public string stepDescription { get; set; } //string to hold step description

    public Input()
    {
        //initialize lists
        Steps = new List<string>();
        StepDescriptions = new List<string>();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The web is stateless. Every time a request is made a new instance of the controller is created, and therefore a new instance of `Input input;` - you need to persist the data (e.g. to a database). And why do you have all those inputs generated by `EditorFor()` outside your form?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I felt something like this was going on; that's very helpful, thank you. To answer your question, I wrote the BeginForm line in a desperate attempt to make sure the list in Input was being accessed. I'll be changing that now though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each request is stateless, you need to post the entire list of steps and then redisplay that in your view.

I'm not sure what the Input class is, but ideally it would contain a List of steps that would be the model of your View. You would then post that to your AddStep method, add the new step, and then rerender the list to the View.